# Problem with time intervals with given start time and end time c#

Tags: c#, time, intervals

I am trying to develop a simple app for my upskill for c#, however I am stuck and new to the functionality of time with c#,

**what I need:**

I have a 3 text boxes that will contain start time, end time and time interval.

say user entered 7:00 AM , 12:00 PM , and 60 minutes it will store it inside a datatable and add it inside a listbox.

7:00 AM

8:00 AM

9:00 AM

10:00 AM

11:00 AM

12:00 AM

***current approach:***

I think I need to use the `DateTime.AddMinutes(interval)` but how am I going to arrive to the logic of it will stop if it reaches the end time? using the DateTime method? I am really confused on what to use, I saw TimeRange, TimeSpan etc.

Comment: What should the result be if the user enters 8:00PM, 1:00 AM, 60 minutes?

Comment: @barn then it should be like this

8:00 
9:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
01:00 AM

Comment: @Barns you're right! it did not output the correct results...i have unmarked the answer.

Comment: Down on analyzing the comments from OP is see that OP has implemented something. I think OP should provide some details of his part of implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan and DateTime together (to calculate and print respectively)

```
TimeSpan start = DateTime.Parse("7:00 AM").TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan end = DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM").TimeOfDay;

TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0);

// If Start is bigger than end, Add a day to the end.
if (start > end)
    end = end.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine((new DateTime() + start).ToString("hh:mm tt"));

    start = start.Add(interval);
    if (start > end)
        break;

}
```

Output looks like this,

```
07:00 AM
08:00 AM
09:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 PM
```

[MS Documentation on TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: hi @jawad thx for the wonderful logic and knowledge,  lets say i ddnt want to just output it in a console, and would like to store every value inside a datatable and add it inside a listbox, is that possible?

Comment: Point I was making was that you can get a variable inside the loop and you can save that to DB or form however you want. Printing shows a variable and value behind it.

Comment: tried to input 8:00 PM and 01:00 AM and the results ddnt match the desired output

Comment: this is the closes answer I can get, knowing that I can just put an exception if the user entered PM to AM since there was no option for dates but only time.

Comment: if start is bigger than end to begin with, add a day to the end so that loop goes through two days worth of hours (instead of within the day). see the if statement in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeSpan` with boolean logical operator to test if the `currentTime` is less than your `endTime`.

Below is example code.

```
TimeSpan startTime;
int interval;
TimeSpan tInterval = new TimeSpan(interval, 0, 0);
TimeSpan endTime;
TimeSpan currentTime = startTime;

while( (currentTime = startTime + tInterval) <= endTime)
{
    // add currentTime to list box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of the issue with the End Times being "earlier" than the Start Time:

```
    private static void TestTimeSpan()
    {
        int minutes = 60;
        var interval = new TimeSpan(0,minutes,0);
        TimeSpan start = DateTime.Parse("7:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan end = DateTime.Parse("1:00 AM").TimeOfDay;

        //End of input data--start of solution
        var diffSpan = end - start;
        var diffMinutes = diffSpan.TotalMinutes >  0 ? diffSpan.TotalMinutes : diffSpan.TotalMinutes + (60 * 24);
        var myTimeList = new List<TimeSpan>();

        for(int i = 0; i < diffMinutes + minutes; i += minutes)
        {
            myTimeList.Add(start);
            start = start.Add(interval);
        }

        myTimeList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine((new DateTime() + x).ToString("hh:mm tt")));
    }
```

---

**EDIT**
Creating a sequence of Time values based in two input times and an interval is straight forward until the "start time" is earlier than the "end time", because just checking to see if the "end time" is greater than the start time fails your algorithm immediately.

This code utilizes the fact that there are only 24 hours in the day. Since the interval value is given in minutes, we can use that to section those minutes into "steps" of time. This code proceeds to step through each interval in time and capture the time at that step and save that in a `List` of `TimeSpan` (the captured value could easily be of type `string`--formatted as desired).

The trick here is when the "end time" is earlier than the "start time" we get a negative `TimeSpan` which is then used to calculate the steps to the "end time" on the next day. This is where the (60 * 24) [60 minutes x 24 hrs] part comes in to create the correct "diffMinutes" using a ternary operator.

After that the code simple iterates over the `List` "myTimeList" to write the formatted `TimeSpan` to the console. However, this 'List' is just a portable collection that can be sent anywhere in you code to do anything needed.

There are lots of other solutions, this one just seems straightforward, to me.

Comment: thanks ! I did try your solution however, it iterated up until 1 PM which is not the case, I think this is the behavior because 7 pm to 1 am is the other day? one question lets say I want to add every "time" into a data table is it possible instead of a List?

Comment: Sure, you just need to create the data structure and add the values to the rows in each iteration of the loop, or just use "myTimeList" and iterate the values to a query. I would need more info on what your requirements are, but should be no issue

Comment: Basically, the output has been created in a consumable structure. You can use that output to create any other data structure necessary.

Comment: Ah! I corrected the error with "diffMinutes" . In my attempt at trying to make it more elegant before posting it I made a fatal error. Should be corrected, now. Best of luck!

Comment: yours is probably the best answer here, since it also handles exceptions but can I request something? Since I am just a beginning @ c# , would you mind explaining some of the line of codes ? Appreciated!